# Swift array get new index of element after filtering

Tags: arrays, swift

Suppose that I have this array:

```
let a = [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]
```

and my favorited number is 4 (index = 4).

Now the array is filtered negative number like this

```
let b = a.filter { $0 >= 0 } // [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

And my favorited number (4) now have index = 2.

I mean how do I know it by code (my favorited index is 2 now) via an elegant way?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of `index(of:)`? Is that not elegant enough?

Comment: @Sweeper This api require Element to be an Equatable

Answer (score 0):

Count how many elements preceding your “favorite” were not discarded. That is the new index of your favorite:

```
let a = [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]
let aFavoriteIndex = 4

let b = a.filter({ $0 >= 0 })
let bFavoriteIndex = a.prefix(aFavoriteIndex).filter({ $0 >= 0 }).count
b[bFavoriteIndex] // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

just save the value, and use `index(of:)` to find the new index

```
let v = a[4]
let newIndex = a.filter { $0 >= 0 }.index(of:v)
```

Comment: Hi, this api require Element to be an Equatable